# Configparser python giving error while trying to access any value [Python]

Tags: python-3.x, keyerror, configparser

I am using configparser to store username and password for a project I am developing. The file **Info.ini** has the following:

```
[Username]
user1 = Admin

[Password]
user1 = 


[Other]
firsttimeopen = True
```

The idea here is that, if firsttimeopen = True, then the password the user has inputted is stored instead of validated. Otherwise, the value of **['Password']['User1']** is compared with user input, and user is given access to the rest of the application.

To do this, I tried the following:

```
configs = configparser.ConfigParser()

with open('Info.ini', 'r') as configfile:
    configs.read(configfile)


class verifyLogin():
    def __init__(self, user, passw):
        self.username = user
        self.password = passw

        
        if configs['Other']['firsttimeopen'] == "True":
            self.CreatePassword()
        
        else:
            self.verifyLoginFunc()

    def verifyLoginFunc(self):
        if self.password == configs['Password']['User1']:
            print("ENTER")  

        else:
            print("NO")

    def CreatePassword(self):
        
        configs.set('Password', 'User1', self.password)
        configs.set('Other', 'firsttimeopen', 'False')  
        

        with open('info.ini', 'w') as configfile:
             configs.write(configfile)
```

However, this throws the following error:

`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\?\Documents\Programming\Python\IA\LoginGUI.py", line 81, in clicked
    verifyLogin(username, password)
  File "c:\Users\?\Documents\Programming\Python\IA\LoginGUI.py", line 17, in __init__
    if configs['Password']['firsttimeopen'] == "True":
  File "C:\Users\?\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\configparser.py", line 964, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Password'
```

**PS:** Idk if this is important or not, but to remake/delete the .ini file for testing I have another file **test.py**:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config['Username'] = {'User1': 'Admin'}
config['Password'] = {'User1': ''}
config['Other'] = {'firsttimeopen': "True"}

with open('info.ini', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Main error

Use `configs.read('Info.ini')` instead `configs.write(...)` to read config file. 
See example 1 on this [tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/python-configparser-example/)

## From my test

I used the exactly same Init.ini file, but scripted python3 on its terminal

```
┌────(レナトの将軍)-[stackoverflow]
└─ $ python3
Python 3.10.8 (main, Oct 13 2022, 21:13:48) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import configparser
>>> configs = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> configs.read(open('Info.ini', 'r'))
[]
>>> configs.read('Info.ini')
['Info.ini']
>>> configs.items
<bound method RawConfigParser.items of <configparser.ConfigParser object at 0x7f15ed167d00>>
>>> configs['Other']
<Section: Other>
>>> configs['Other']['firsttimeopen']
'True'
>>>
```

You can see `configs.read(open('Info.ini', 'r'))` returns empty list.

## How you can you do it in a pro-level

### Store login and passwords in a structured database

You can do it using configparser, but its not made for this. Try using a structured database like SQLite3.

### Never store real password

Save the sha512 (or something like) hash of new passwords. On a login attempt, you have to hash the input password and then compare with the storaged hash. Its recommended to use salt also.

Comment: that was an error on stackoverflow, not my code. Not sure how that happened but in my code configs['Others'] is written and the same error is displayed

Comment: Try something like print(configs), then we can see if its inside or not.

Comment: A database is a good idea here, yes but I thought it wouldnt really be necessary as in this program, security really doesnt matter (Unlike the pro world). If configparser doesnt work, ill do that instead. Here is the output for print(config): 

<configparser.ConfigParser object at 0x0000026B554E3FD0>

Comment: Hmmm I think also you have to use configs.read(...) instead of configs.write(...), in order to load them

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. Something I did notice, however was that when I moved the code of test.py into my main code, it works. How though? Also now, the values will reset each time.

Comment: Well, replace that `configs.write...` by `configs.read('Info.ini')`. Check my new edit. I tested here and it works :)